# Search and update single document from firestore collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to search single document in Firestore with specific query. Then update record if found. And equivalent to `where` on collection but on a doc.

```
const usersRef = Firebase.firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(currentUser.uid);

      usersRef.get().then(user => {
       // get record where user.dayData.date == Date.now() or something

      }).then(() => // update record)
```

// db datastructure is like this. Will like to update totalhours for specific dates

```
        projectData: {
            dayData: [
                { date: 1564656952780, totalHours: 15 },
                { date: 1568659952780, totalHours: 65 },
                { date: 1563659952780, totalHours: 15 },
                { date: 1564651234567, totalHours: 5 }
            ],
            userData: { displayName: "Ajiboye John" }
        }
    },
```

Comment: It looks like you're really close to solving this on your own.  What is the specific problem that you're running into?  Is something not working the way you expect?

Comment: I can't seem to figure how to get the data I need. I tried doing it by normal js filter. But then that is not async and I can't find a way to update.

`usersRef.get().then(user => {
        const allUserData = user.data();
        const { dayData } = allUserData.projectData;
        const dayHours = dayData
          .filter(day => {
         return   day.date = Date.now()
          })
          .then(() => {
            dayHours.update({ totalHours: 50 });
          })
     
`